# Create a table using Vpython

Tags: vpython

Use of the VPython library to create a small table in a simulated 3D space

this is what I've got

```
top = box(pos=vector(-1,4,4), 
        axis=vector(-1.5,0,-1.5),
        size=vector(18,0.29,10),
        up=vector(5,25,5),
        color = color.blue)



leg1 = cylinder(pos=(-3,-3,0),
                axis=vector(0,7,0), radius=0.45,
                color = color.green )
leg2 = cylinder(pos=vector(3.5,-5,3),
                axis=vector(0,9,0), radius=0.45,
                color = color.green )
leg3 = cylinder(pos=vector(10.5,-3.9,2),
                axis=vector(0,9,0), radius=0.45,
                color = color.green )
leg4 = cylinder(pos=vector(-11.5,-6.5,-2.2),
                axis=vector(0,11,0), radius=0.45,
                color = color.green )
```

[image: This is the output I am getting][image: But I want something like this but turned upside down]

The first image is what I got and the second image is what I want, but turned upside down as a table would

Comment: You should modify the vector direction, try around different values (positives, negatives)

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing out the table top and legs on paper
The up of the table top should be default
The legs should have the same "length"
To have the legs point downwards use a negative y

If the center of your table is 0,0,0 then the legs will reflect each other's positions in reference to that.